# Why doesn't my beamer function work well?

Tags: beamer, equations, pdftex

I have already tried {ctexbeamer}/{beamer}+{ctex} , {amssymb}.
The function works well in my ctexart environment. Why won't it work in beamer?

My code:

```
% 中文ppt
\documentclass[10.5pt,UTF8]{beamer}

\usepackage{ctex}

% 英文ppt

%\documentclass[UTF8]{beamer}

% ppt 模板风格

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{geometry}

% 数学公式

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{stix2}    % 包含 \leftrightarrowaccent{T} 用双向箭头表示张量

% 文献引用

\usepackage{cite}

% 图片引用

\usepackage{graphicx}

% 引用高亮（beamer默认使用，添加引用报错）

% \usepackage[backref]{hyperref}

% 文献引用存在下划线

\usepackage[strings]{underscore}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

%\usepackage{comment}

\title{开题报告}

\subtitle{mysubject}

\author{myname}

\institute[*]{ my school}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

...codes before...

        \begin{frame}

            \frametitle{流体动力学基本方程}

            \begin{itemize}

                \item 流体动力学基本方程

                \item 质量方程：

                \begin{equation}

                    \begin{cases}

                        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho + \nabla \cdot 
(\rho \vec{u}) = 0 

                    \end{cases}

                \end{equation}

                \item 动量方程：

                \item 能量方程：

            \end{itemize}

        \end{frame}

...codes after...

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Sho a complete document, please.

Comment: No-one have any idea what you are talking about here. Provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I wanted to add a picture here but I don't know how... I just register an account 10 min before I asked this question

Comment: @Toby Please don't remove the code indentation. Without it, syntax highlighting etc. does not work.

Comment: I can't compile your code (I don't have the fonts to use ctex), but does it work if you remove `\usepackage{stix2}`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `10.5pt` is not a valid class option. You can use `10pt` or `11pt` but not random values in between. It is also not necessary to load the `geometry`, `amsmath`, amssymb` and `graphicx` packages, beamer already loads them for you.

Comment: Does it work if you remove \usepackage{stix2}? Currently it does.

Comment: I am not sure whether 10.5pt is a valid class option but my compiler (Vscode Latex Workshop + texlive) doesn't tell me there is anything wrong here.

Comment: @Toby The class option will simply be ignored, you could as well leave it out. Beamer only implements the options 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt and 20pt

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

#### Use the `professionalfonts` beamer font theme:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{stix2}    % 包含 \leftrightarrowaccent{T} 用双向箭头表示张量

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
                \begin{equation}
                    \begin{cases}
                        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho + \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u}) = 0 
                    \end{cases}
                \end{equation}
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remove the `stix2` package:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

%\usepackage{stix2}    % 包含 \leftrightarrowaccent{T} 用双向箭头表示张量

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
                \begin{equation}
                    \begin{cases}
                        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho + \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u}) = 0 
                    \end{cases}
                \end{equation}
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried "Remove the stix2 package" and it seems helpful.
I am still wondering why it doesn't work in a beamer file; it works farely well in my ctexart file.(article + ctex)

Comment: Again I tried "Use the professionalfonts beamer font theme". It also works well. Thx again.

Comment: @Toby Which one to choose will depend on which font you prefer.

Comment: Yeah I see... I would choose professionalfonts, because \leftrightarrowaccent{T} looks far better than \vec{\vec{T}}. lol